# Yii2 if only id parameter is provided redirect to id plus slug

Tags: php, redirect, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

My current setup has the following URL structure

http://somedomain/blog/1/title

If the slug title part is wrong it will redirect to the correct slug however if you entered the following url you'd get a 404 (no slug provided):

http://somedomain/blog/1

Now I want to redirect the user to the proper URL with the slug, for example on stackoverflow if you enter https://stackoverflow.com/users/1917403 if will add my username to the end.

Url manager

```
    'urlManager' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [
            'blog/<id:\d+>/<slug:[-a-zA-Z 0-9]+>' => 'blog/view',
        ],
    ],
```

And here is my controller view action

```
public function actionView($id, $slug = null)
{

    $model = $this->findModel($id);
    $model->author_info = json_decode($model->author_info, true); 

    if ($slug != $model->slug) {
        return $this->redirect(['blog/view', 'id' => $id, 'slug' => $model->slug]);
    }

    return $this->render('view', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The rule you created doesn't match since the slug is not found. It will simply bypass it.

So you can either use the [`defaults`-functionality](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-urlrule.html#$defaults-detail) for the rule to make one of the parameters (slug in this case) optional, or just specify a second rule without the slug part.

Example for solution 1 would be:

```
'urlManager' => [
    'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules' => [ 
        [
           'pattern' => 'blog/<id:\d+>/<slug:[-a-zA-Z 0-9]+>',
           'route' => 'blog/view',
           'defaults' => ['slug' => null],
        ],            
    ],
],
```